# System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name not consistent

Tags: c#, asp.net

In our Project we are using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to get the UserID with Domain. for few pages like say, login or home Page or many of them it is returning the Username as expected with domainName which is

DomainName\UserID

When we want to are trying to upload a file using a Usercontrol on one of the Pages, it throws exception as it is returning Directly the Username

like Harry,Burlington instead  of dom\Hburlingt .

we are using Windows Authentication mode in our Web,config and sample code thats throwing the exception is

```
public static string GetCurrUsersLoginIdentity()
    {
        string name = "";
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
            name = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        else
        {
            WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            if (id != null)
                name = id.Name;
        }

        //If we still don't have a name then something is seriously wrong
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException("Coult not retrieve IDSID information for user.");

        return name;
```

Answer (score 0):

`User.Identity` and `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` are two different things:

[User.Identity on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0(v=vs.110).aspx%20User.Identity%20on%20MSDN) returns a `System.Security.Principal` object.

[WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx%20Windows.Identity%20on%20MSDN) returns a `System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal` object.

So it is no surprise that you are seeing two different names.

BTW, the name of your method `GetCurrUsersLoginIdentity` is misleading, since it returns the user's name not the identity object itself.

And also, your exception message contains a spelling error: `Coult not retrieve IDSID information for user.`

Comment: Yeah, Thats right. But since we are using a WebApp it will always go into the first If statement and actual exception is being thrown there as we get the Username directly but not domain separated. We implemente dit as to foolproof way to get the Userinfo.

Comment: I bet you that you are wrong.  For whatever reason in your WebApp the `HttpContext.Current` is actually null and it is going into else second branch instead.

Comment: Okay, one thing I just found out was, when returning domainname\UserID its using NTLM authentication and returns IPrincipal Object. But when it is returning the UserName itself, the same statement itself using one of our Data Access Layer Class Type, which is <DAL.UserInfo> why same statement is behaving differently? Any inputs.. And BTW this Method was written sometime in 2013 and its working fine since then ans started throwing error from few hours back..so I suspect some setting outside of this code might have affected